# How can i get space utilized by Query when its executing in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want result such that it shows amount of space used by stored procedure/query when it's executing.

Comment: What do you mean by space? you mean memory? CPU? IO?

Comment: Yes I m asking about memory